# Automating a python script to run twice a day

Tags: python, woocommerce-rest-api, windows-task-scheduler

I am having issues attempting to automate my python script to automatically get our estore orders at 9am and noon each day. The program works as expected when ran through my environment and when being run as an executable file that I converted the script to(i.e. me double clicking to run it like an application).

My problem occurs when I try to automate this process with windows task scheduler. For about a week I had the process working seamlessly as I had the program running on our VM connected to our server and it was always on and would run the script everyday at 9am and noon. Now I am getting Timeout issues "**httpsconnectionpool(host='https' port=443)**' and ***ImportError: cannot import name 'exceptions' from partially initialized module 'pip._vendor.urllib3' (most likely due to a circular import)*** as an error. I am open to other methods to automate this if someone could recommend that or point out the potential fix for my error. Thank you in advance.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import os
from woocommerce import API
import urllib3


wcapi = API(
    url="My_URL",   
    consumer_key="my_key",  # Your consumer key
    consumer_secret="My_secret",  # Your consumer secret
    wp_api=True,  # Enable the WP REST API integration
    version="wc/v3")


yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)
today = date.today()
time = datetime.now()
current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
file_date = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H%M")

r = wcapi.get(f"orders?after={yesterday}")

meta = []

if r.status_code in range(200, 299): 
    orders = r.json()

    # set the path that you want to save the file
    dir_path = "\Online_Orders\Estore Orders\"
    # set the name of the file with todays date
    file_name = f"orders-{file_date}.csv"
    # create the full file path
    file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)

    with open(file_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf_8') as csv_file:

        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        # delcare all of the column headers in the csv file
        header = ['id', 'status', 'date_created', 'total', 'shipping_total', 'total_tax', 'sku', 'item_name',
                  'item_quantity', 'item_price', 'item_total',
                  'first_name', 'last_name', 'company', 'email', 'phone',
                  'billing_address1', 'billing_address2', 'billing_city', 'billing_state',
                  'billing_postcode', 'billing_country',
                  'shipping_address1', 'shipping_address2', 'shipping_city',
                  'shipping_state', 'shipping_postcode', 'shipping_country', 'customer_note',
                  'shipping_method_title', 'shipping_method_id', 'payment_method', 'payment_method_title', 'meta']

        # write headers to csv file
        writer.writerow(header)

        for order in orders:

            # create dictionary reference variables for nested dictionaries to clean up keys below
            shipping = order['shipping']
            billing = order['billing']
            shipping_lines = order['shipping_lines']

            # this for look goes through the list of shipping_line items for shipping information and matches the pairs
            # in dictionary format to be accessed below
            for ship_info in shipping_lines:
                pass

            for line_item in order['line_items']:
                # create the new row of data to send to csv
                row = []

                # create a dictionary out of a list of meta data and assign the meta data list to the meta var
                mt = line_item['meta_data']
                for m in mt:
                    if m['key'] == 'vpc-cart-data':
                        meta = m

                # order information
                row.append(order['id'])
                row.append(order['status'])
                row.append(order['date_created'])
                row.append(order['total'])
                row.append(order['shipping_total'])
                row.append(order['total_tax'])
                row.append(line_item['sku'])
                row.append(line_item['name'])
                row.append(line_item['quantity'])
                row.append(line_item['price'])
                row.append(line_item['total'])

                # customer information
                row.append(billing['first_name'])
                row.append(billing['last_name'])
                row.append(billing['company'])
                row.append(billing['email'])
                row.append(billing['phone'])

                # billing information
                row.append(billing['address_1'])
                row.append(billing['address_2'])
                row.append(billing['city'])
                row.append(billing['state'])
                row.append(billing['postcode'])
                row.append(billing['country'])

                # shipping information
                row.append(shipping['address_1'])
                row.append(shipping['address_2'])
                row.append(shipping['city'])
                row.append(shipping['state'])
                row.append(shipping['postcode'])
                row.append(shipping['country'])
                row.append(order['customer_note'])
                row.append(ship_info['method_title'])
                row.append(ship_info['method_id'])

                # payment information
                row.append(order['payment_method'])
                row.append(order['payment_method_title'])

                # meta
                row.append(meta)

                # write each row to the csv file
                writer.writerow(row)

                # clear accumulated meta data after row is written
                meta.clear()
```

Comment: Your first error sounds like there could be some sort of proxy or some other issue.  Not sure if you have one in your work environment (not sure why it would work normally but not as a scheduled task however).  Can try setting the HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY environment variables in the script and see if that works?

It's also highly likely that you just need retry-logic - networks are fickle and timeouts not uncommon.

Comment: Thanks Eddie, I will try to mess around with those to see if it helps at all.